# Macbook Pro 2014 shuts down at random intervals

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, restart

Thanks @fbara for suggestion to add more details

Device: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

OS: 10.11.6 (15G1004)

pmset -g log from one of the times it occurred

> UUID: (null) 2016-09-07 20:15:11 -0700 Start                  powerd
>   process is started 2016-09-07 20:15:11 -0700
>     Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using Batt(Charge: 81) 2016-09-07
>   20:15:11 -0700 Assertions             Kernel Idle sleep preventers:
>   IODisplayWrangler 2016-09-07 20:15:43 -0700 Assertions            PID
>   104(hidd) Created UserIsActive
>   "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" 00:00:00  id:0x0x9000001f5
>   [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp] 2016-09-07 20:16:52 -0700 Assertions
>     PID 261(Google Chrome) Created NoDisplaySleepAssertion "Playing
>   video" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500000223 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser
>   kDisp]

Comment: Please don't start a new question to add details, edit your original which will then add it to the review queue to be re-opened.

Comment: I concur with Tetsujin - rewrite your original question.  Also, issue the following command `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"` and post the results.    You may also want to run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.   This will help you determine if you have a hardware issue

Comment: Ah that makes sense. My thought was to open a new one because the original has -4 votes, so I figured it was as good as dead. Is that false?

Comment: Previous shutdown cause: -128

Comment: Reference code PPT004 -- the battery requires service

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you also check your Macbook for excessive dust inside!

I have a Macbook pro which shutdown randomly (and gave the shutdown cause -128 error, and also the reference code PPT004 - the battery requires service). When I cleaned the build up dust it started functioning normally again!

I just removed the backplate and used a can of compressed air to clean it. Check https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Mac_Laptop to see how you can remove the backplate of your model.

PS: Try not to touch any parts inside, because of static discharge